# How to open SharePoint 2010 document in C# Word add-in

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, ms-office, add-in

I'm developing an MS Word 2010 add-in (using C#), which has a custom Ribbon tab. In that tab there is a button, which should open a particular Word document (MyTemplate.docx), which is located in SharePoint 2010 server's Shared Documents library.
The URL of my development server (internal) is 'http://sharepoint2010'.
I'm trying to use SP object model elements, such as SPSite, SPWeb, etc...
When I try :

```
SPSite site = new SPSite(@"http://sharepoint2010");
```

I get error: "**The Web application at 'http://sharepoint2010' could not be found**"

I do have a valid Web Service Reference:

```
HomeDataContext dc = new HomeDataContext(new Uri("http://sharepoint2010/_vti_bin/listdata.svc"));
```

which allows me to obtain a listing of documents in the Shared Documents library. I'm able to iterate through that list and obtain individual SharedDocumentItem, but I don't understand how to open it as a Word document.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use SharePoint object model in a remote-access scenario. The object model (mostly represented by `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`) depends on the server code, so it can be used on the SharePoint server *only*. That's why instantiating `SPSite` will *always* throw an exception.

Also note that the URL passed to `SPSite` has nothing to do with accessing a site via HTTP, web services or whatever. It's interpreted as the server-side locator of the site collection.

Should you really need it client-side, have a look [client object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247.aspx).